# Connecting a home network to the Internet via modem + router

Tags: home-networking, cable

I have a modem and a router (as separate units). I have cable Internet. So far I've only connected one computer via the modem. How do I connect a network via the router?

Answer (score 1):

You can usually replicate the settings of your PC on your router. You will need to find out how your PC presently connects to the Internet. Many commodity routers are able to handle PPPoE, DHCP and other common methods used to obtain a network connection to the Internet.  If your router does not, you may want to consider getting one that does or updating its firmware to one that does, such as dd-wrt.